# Separar string que não tem delimitadores

Tags: c++, string

Minha intenção é simplesmente pegar uma parte de uma string que eu sei que da posição 0 até a posição 29, por exemplo, contém um nome próprio. E da posição 30 até a posição 45, está o telefone associado ao nome da pessoa. Eu posso inventar uma função assim mas se tem pronta em alguma biblioteca eu quero usá-la.
Um código hipotético segue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   FILE * pFile;
   pFile = fopen ("lista.txt" , "r");
   string str1, str2, str_fonte;
   fgets ( str_fonte , 45 , pFile ); 
   str1.copia( str_fonte,  0, 29 ); // código hipotético, alguma função parecida?
   str2.copia( str_fonte, 30, 45 ); // código hipotético, alguma função parecida?
   close(pFile);
return 0;
}
```

Não achei nada ainda, enquanto isso fiz minha própria função, espero que seja útil para alguém.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string copia (string fonte, size_t l_inf, size_t l_sup)
{
    size_t i = l_inf;
    size_t j = 0;
    size_t tam = 1 + (l_sup - l_inf);
    string copiado;
    copiado.reserve(tam);

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
    {
        copiado.push_back(' ');
    }
    
    for ( i = l_inf; i <= l_sup; i++ )
    {
        copiado[j] = fonte[i];
        j++;
    }

    return copiado;
}

int main() {
    string test = {"Testando a nova funcao copia ( string fonte, size_t l_inf, size_t l_sup )."};
    cout << test << endl;
    string teste;
    teste = copia(test, 11, 27);
    cout << "[" << teste << "]" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

A saída do programa será:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso responde sua pergunta? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2114388/14100521

Comment: Veja [`std::string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Comment: Não use cumprimentos em perguntas ou respostas: Ref: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Eu posso inventar uma função assim mas se tem pronta em alguma
> biblioteca eu quero usá-la

- Em C++, como sugerido neste tópico e na resposta que citou, pode usar `substr()` da classe string para separar os campos, entre muitas alternativas.
- Em C `memcpy()` seria a opção clássica, e que também funcionaria em C++.

C e C++ são linguagens bem distintas. E vai depender também de como vai ler isso e o resto do programa. No seu exemplo os campos tem tamanho fixo e não está determinado que sejam strings C, com um zero ao final do nome e outro ao final do telefone.

### Exemplos

Para esse arquivo lista.txt

```
0123456789 1234567890123456789CCCAAANNNNNNNNN1
X0123456789 1234567890123456789CCCZAANNNNNNNN2
XY0123456789 1234567890123456789CCCZAANNNNNNN3
XYW0123456789 1234567890123456789CCCZAANNNNNN4
XYWZ0123456789 1234567890123456789CCCZAANNNNN5
```

Esta seria a saída dos simples exemplos que seguem, em C usando `memcpy()` e em C++ usando `substr()`

```
Nome : '0123456789 1234567890123456789' Fone: 'CCCAAANNNNNNNNN1'
Nome : 'X0123456789 123456789012345678' Fone: '9CCCZAANNNNNNNN2'
Nome : 'XY0123456789 12345678901234567' Fone: '89CCCZAANNNNNNN3'
Nome : 'XYW0123456789 1234567890123456' Fone: '789CCCZAANNNNNN4'
Nome : 'XYWZ0123456789 123456789012345' Fone: '6789CCCZAANNNNN5'
```

#### Em C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

int main(void)
{
    char    registro[47] = { 0 }; // vai ler aqui
    char saida[] = "\
Nome : '1111222233aaaabbbbdd1111222233' \
Fone: '1111222233aaabbb'"; // e gravar aqui

    FILE* in = fopen("lista.txt","r"); // deste arquivo
    int n = fread( (void*) &registro[0], sizeof(registro), 1, in);
    while (n > 0)
    {
        memcpy(saida + 8, registro, 30);
        memcpy(saida + 47, registro + 30, 16);
        printf("%s\n", saida);
        n = fread((void*)&registro[0], sizeof(registro), 1, in);
    }
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

Ou em C++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    string arquivo = "lista.txt"; // arquivo
    ifstream entrada{ arquivo };
    string linha{};
    getline(entrada, linha);
    while (linha.length() > 0)
    {   std::cout << "Nome : \"" << linha.substr(0, 30) <<
            "\"\tFone: '" << linha.substr(30, 16) << "'\n";
        getline(entrada, linha);
    }
    entrada.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Olá @arfneto, não sei se entendi tua observação sobre meu exemplo mas acho que tu quis dizer que eu não precisaria inserir \0 no fim da string de retorno porque o tipo string já trata das adequações necessárias. Obrigado, fiz um update no código e vou aceitar sua resposta, pena que não posso pontuar ela como útil.

Comment: O que está gravado no disco está além dessas distinções de strings ou qualquer coisa. É só um arquivo. Você não postou um arquivo de origem, então eu escrevi de acordo com o que parecia certo :)  Eis o que acontece: se as strings são null-terminated você pode ler direto com `strcpy()` e usar para construir suas strings. Mas aí vai perder a comodidade de poder digitar os dados num editor de texto. Se quer fazer assim e quiser posso alterar os exemplos.

Comment: Tudo bem está ótimo seus exemplos, eu que misturei C com C++. Super valeu seus comentários.